# Is there a point to the mound / sunlight room in the Temple of Hylia?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

In the Temple of Hylia, there's a room behind the Bird save statue that has a mound, and a few items to help you recover.  Besides giving you some life hearts, is there anything else you can do in this room?  The light coming from above seems like it would have some sort of meaning.

Here's the room I'm talking about (sorry, best picture I could find on short notice):

[image: Temple of Hylia mound room]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this room has a use.

To keep spoilers at a minimum, it is part of the quest to find the Thunder Dragon and learn Nayru's part of the Ballad of the Hero.

Comment: I really need to finish the game all the way so that I stop asking these questions. Thanks!